# How to set Steam options from a batch file?

Tags: steam

I repair computers and often need to reconfigure or reinstall the software.  Some users want Steam installed.  I have a batch file that installs all the requested / required apps, including Steam.  Steam has the ability to set various options from within its GUI, but that requires logging in.  Besides, setting things through a GUI violates the whole idea of a batch file: run just one file and let it automatically do everything that's needed with no further operator interaction.

I found out how to keep Steam from auto-launching by running the following command after Steam is installed:

```
REG DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /V "Steam" /F
```

But I need to set several other parameters / options as well.  Logging into Steam to get to the GUI is simply **not** an option.  How can I set things from the batch file?

Comment: I documented much of Steam's config data up to Dec 5, 2017, in my project [Steam-Data](https://github.com/l3laze/Steam-Data), but it's pretty outdated now. This could be a good start if you're willing to put in the work to figure out what you need, but it's worth remembering that the Steam client may destroy existing data, and only some config data was (is?) global. What are you looking to set?

Answer (score 1):

This will vary wildly with the setting you want to set. There is no known "remote control" or API to control everything that same way the Steam GUI does it. But if you can discover where a setting is stored (either in a config file or in the Windows Registry) you can write batch commands to set it or change values. These changes will (usually) have to be made while Steam is not running (either foreground or background -- when the Steam client exits, it could overwrite any changes you sneakily made while it was running).

The Steam root directory contains most settings. *(and you might be pleased to discover that Steam does not need to be installed: or rather, once it is installed, that root directory can be copied to other computer unmodified, and will run just fine)*

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve` contains many settings on Windows

That [Steam-Data](https://github.com/l3laze/Steam-Data) project from [l3l-aze](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/203077/l3l-aze) (referenced in the comments above) is rather extensive, and represents a lot of discovery work on many of the specific settings.